# What is the status of deprecated JError and what is the suggested replacement

Tags: jerror, deprecated

JError is shown as deprecated (as of 12.3), but is still widely used in the core. The [API docs](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JError.html) say that its status is deprecated - 4.0 Will be removed without replacement, but its still alive and well in 4.0.0 Alpha 1. Is it still being deprecated?

If it truly is deprecated and we are supposed to stop using it, what is the alternative for the following situation. In the save method of a component model subclassing JModelAdmin, and you want return false to indicate that there was a problem with the data, how do you add a message to the error box?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Whats the correct way for exception handling?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/223/whats-the-correct-way-for-exception-handling)

Comment: And https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/15973/12352 if these preexisting pages fail to resolve your question, please update your question to isolate what they fail to address for your situation.  Many of my posted answers to [mysql] questions use a try-catch block and send a message to the "error box" via `enqueueMessage()`. For instance: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/23882/12352

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's still being deprecated.

`JError::raiseError()` should be replaced with native exceptions.

`JError::raiseWarning()` and `JError::raiseNotice` should be replaced with calls to application's `enqueueMessage()` method to display warnings/notices.

See [Potential backward compatibility issues in Joomla 4](https://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_4) for code migration tips.

Comment: How can throwing native exceptions work in the context I've described? When you're in your components model's save method, and you've parsed the input and found it to be in error and want to redisplay the form to the user with an error message at the top, then throwing an exception will not achieve this. Also, the core of 4 is still using JError to do exactly what I'm describing.

Comment: Use application's `enqueueMessage()` method to display warnings/notices.

Comment: Also, if you're testing J4 always use the latest nightly build. I can't confirm that `JError` is present in current nightly.